# pandas - checking business days and replacing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Assuming the following dataframe:

```
date | id
2020-12-11 | A
2020-12-15 | A
2020-04-09 | B
2020-04-09 | C
2020-04-08 | C
2021-03-11 | D
2021-03-12 | D
2021-01-24 | E
2021-01-19 | E
```

Desired output:

```
date | id
2020-12-11 | A
2020-12-12 | 0
2020-04-09 | B
2020-04-09 | C
2020-04-08 | C
2021-03-11 | D
2021-03-12 | D
2021-01-19 | E
2021-01-20 | 0
```

Basically, if id is duplicate, we want to check if the dates are consecutive business days. If consecutive business days, keep both; else, only keep the smaller date, remove the latter date and replace it with the next business day, with id '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some assumptions:

```
def bus_day_dup_rep(x):

    bd1 = pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(n = 1)
    bdp1 = x.iloc[0,0] + bd
    bdm1 = x.iloc[0,0] - bd

    if x.shape[0] > 1:
    
        if x.iloc[1,0] != bdp1 and x.iloc[1,0] != bdm1:
            x.iloc[1,1] = '0'

            if x.iloc[0,0] < x.iloc[1,0]:
                x.iloc[1,0] = bdp1 
            else:
                x.iloc[0,0] = x.iloc[1,0] 
                x.iloc[1,0] = x.iloc[1,0] + bd1 

    return x


df.groupby('id').apply(bus_day_dup_rep)

        date id
0 2020-12-11  A
1 2020-12-14  0
2 2020-04-09  B
3 2020-04-09  C
4 2020-04-08  C
5 2021-03-11  D
6 2021-03-12  D
7 2021-01-19  E
8 2021-01-20  0
```

Assumptions:  Max number IDs per ID is 2.  (Can have only 2 A's).  'date' is not the index.  'date' column is dtype 'datetime64[ns]'.  'date and 'id' are in relative column positions 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: thank you. however, pd.Timedelta('1 day') does not mean '1 business day', it's simply '1 day'

Comment: @richtigga I missed that requirement first pass.  Updated answer to reflect 1 business day.  Note that changes your desired output from 2020-12-12 to 2020-12-14 since 2020-12-12 is a Saturday.  Also realized that I hadn't handled the 'keep the smaller date' requirement.  I added that capability also.